# Label on CCMenuItemImage

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Tell me, please, how to write a button label? I have a code like this:

```
CCMenuItem *Podskazki = [CCMenuItemImage
                                    itemFromNormalImage:@"button.png" selectedImage:@"button1.png" target:self selector:@selector(menuCallbackPodskazki:) ];
            CCMenu *ButtonPodskazki =[CCMenu menuWithItems:Podskazki, nil];
            [ButtonPodskazki alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:20];
            [ButtonPodskazki setPosition:ccp(-Podskazki.contentSize.width/2+size.width,Podskazki.contentSize.height/2)];
            [self addChild:ButtonPodskazki];
```

Comment: add CCMenuItemLabel in CCMenu on same location of ButtonPodskazki.

Answer (score 0):

Add a label to the menu item.

```
CCMenuItem * Podskazki = [CCMenuItemImage
                                itemFromNormalImage:@"button.png" selectedImage:@"button1.png" target:self selector:@selector(menuCallbackPodskazki:) ];
CCLabelTTF *label = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:@"string" fontName:@"font" fontSize:14.0f];
CGSize size = item.boundingBox.size;
label.position = ccp(size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 2.0f);
[Podskazki addChild:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CCMenu *m = [CCMenu menuWithItems:i, nil];
m.position = ccp(0,0);
[l addChild:m];

//Play next
CCSprite *sp = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"friend_letter.png"];
CCLabelTTF *lb = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Tell a friend", nil) fontName:@"42835" fontSize:12];
sp.position = ccp(lb.contentSize.width/2,lb.contentSize.height/2+30);
[lb addChild:sp];
CCMenuItemLabel *i = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:lb target:self selector:@selector(continueAction)];
[i setContentSize:CGSizeMake(MAX(44, i.contentSize.width), MAX(60, i.contentSize.height))];
i.position = ccp(100,100);
[m addChild:i];
```

[image: Here example]